# MonoTouch: how to run app in Simulator 6.0 with SDK 4.4?

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

On my machine I have installed:

- Xcode 4.5
- Xcode 4.4
- MonoTouch 6.x
- MonoTouch 5.2.13

For an older app, I build using Xcode 4.4 and MonoTouch 5.2.13. To do so, I change the paths in the SDK section of MonoDevelop's settings.

However, now I need to test run the app that was built with SDK 4.4 and MT 5.2.13 on the iOS Simulator 6.0. How can I tell MonoDevelop what path for the simulator to use?
The dropdown of the Simulator itself doesn't offer v6.0 because back than with SDK 4.4, there was no v6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not supported in MonoTouch (nor in Xcode for that matter).

That said, you might be able to do the following:

- Build & run your app using the Xcode 4.4 SDK / iOS 5.1 Simulator. Copy the app directory from the simulator (one way to figure out where the app resides is to run it in the simulator using MonoDevelop, then execute `ps aux | grep debugtrack` from a terminal window - this should show the simulator process and the path to the binary).
- Build & run your app using Xcode 4.5 SDK. Figure out again where the app resides like above (since it's a different simulator the directory will change), and replace the contents of it with what you saved in the previous step.
- Now you *might* be able to run the app in the iOS 6 simulator (either with MonoDevelop or by tapping it). Note that since Xcode itself doesn't really allow you to do this, many things may break. The only supported way to test a build using an older SDK is to test it on a real device.

Comment: Wow...that's quite some hassle to go through. I ended up debugging it on the device itself.